# tcpdf : prevent page break within a block

Tags: tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to print some tables of data: one big table (although usually not longer than a page) followed by a second, smaller one.
In some cases, the two tables together are longer than one page, so TCPDF inserts a page break in the middle of the second table. My clients want to avoid that behavior: they would rather have the second table completely on a new page, ie insert the page break *before* the table, if both table cannot fit on a single page.

Of course if both tables fit on one page, no page break should be used.

So does anybody know if there is a way to instruct TCPDF *not* to insert a page break within a given table?

Answer (score 18):

Start a transaction, insert the table, check if you are in a new page, if yes, roll back and add a page before insering your table.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: don't forget the TRUE calling rollback:

```
$this->startTransaction(); 
$start_page = $this->getPage();                       
$this->writeHTMLCell( 0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, false, true, 'C'  );
$end_page = $this->getPage();
if  ($end_page != $start_page) {
    $this->rollbackTransaction(true); // don't forget the true
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->writeHTMLCell( 0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, false, true, 'C'  );
}else{
    $this->commitTransaction();     
}
```

Hope it helps
michel

Comment: It's a bit of an old question, not relevant anymore to me, so I can't test your answer now. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Be careful with this approach to ensure your $html content is never larger than one page. In this event, the end page would ALWAYS not equal the starting page, and the script will simply keep adding blank pages. A flag in your IF statement would allow you to track if you've already added a blank, and allow you to force a stop or warning.

Comment: getPage() can return same value even if content has spilled over page boundry.  I had to calculate printable area and determine if Y had left the current page: `if ($this->getY() >= ($this->getPageHeight() - $this->getMargins()['top'] - $this->getMargins()['bottom']))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This worked perfectly for me.  I am using the latest version of TCPDF in 2024.
I used this method to keep all the totals together.  It always looks bad to have the subtotals on one page, and total on the next page.  I didn't have to worry about page boundaries as the previous comment said - it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

according to docs, there is a option to add nobr="true" to table tag as attribute.

```
 $tbl = <<<EOD
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" nobr="true">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="3" align="center">NON-BREAKING TABLE</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1-1</td>
  <td>1-2</td>
  <td>1-3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps

Answer (score -1):

Calculate a height of the second table in advance. Use a checkPageBreak method to add a page break if needed.